# Can not find header and source files when i create a new project in Qt creater

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am new to Qt. I installed Qt 5 but when i create a new project (Qt widget application) i do not find headers and source files like `main.cpp` and `mainwindow.ui` and `mainwindow.cpp` Although *.pro file is there but nothing else.
`mainwindow.cpp` does appear on the text editor but there is a message above that

> "This file is not the part of any project."

When i checked inside the project directory i can see all the files present but in Qt creator i can not access any of them.
Please help.

Comment: Whats your OS, and how you installed Qt?

Answer (score 0):

The files that Qt Creator generates for you when you create a new project depend on the type of project that you choose to create. F.ex. when you create a new `Empty qmake Project`, only the .pro file is being created. You can choose a different type of project when creating one, so that Qt Creator will auto generate some more files depending on your needs.

You can add new files to your project by right clicking on the main project folder in `Projects` menu and choosing either `Add New...` to create a new file or `Add Existing Files...` to point Qt Creator to the files that you already have.

[image: Adding files to Qt Creator project]

This will add a link to the new file in to the .pro file. Lower is the content of the .pro file after adding a couple of new files to the project.

[image]

You can also edit the .pro file by hand instead of using the IDE, but Qt Creator (and qmake as well) won't know about the files in your project folder until you add them to the .pro file.

Comment: Dorin Botan. The option to add new files and add existing files is disabled. Also *. pro file already has the code to include these files as shown on the screenshot